# how to set a useState constant variable using api variables and dynamic js variables in React.js

Tags: json, reactjs, api, axios, react-hooks

I don't know how to search for this so thats why the title is a bit weird ,I will just post an example.
Basicly I want to know how replace the DATEHERE with the variable date I have created.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function App(loading, result) {
  const [test, setTest] = useState([]);

    var today = new Date(),
        date = "05-01-2021";
    
    const url = "random-api-url"
    
    const getData = async () => {
        const result = await axios.get(url);
        setTest(result.data.example.DATEHERE);
        console.log(result);
      };



 return (
        <div className="App">
          <h1 onClick={getData}>test</h1>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: You want response example date to be set to `test`?

Comment: is your response `result.data.example` coming us object ?

`{"05-01-2021": [] , ...}`

if so use

`result.data.example[date]`

Comment: it would be easy if you can provide the result object structure

Comment: @venkateshpogartha that was what I was looking for thank you

Comment: Just a tip: If you find that getData gets called too many times (will get called on every re-render) try to move the getData into a useEffect-hook https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html - if you only wants your getData function to run once when the component mounts, you can add an empty array as second argument to useEffect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your response **result.data.example** coming as an object?

```
{"05-01-2021": [] , ...}
```

if so use `result.data.example[date]`